# How to exit Far Manager in the current folder of the current tab?

Tags: far-manager

In the past, when I was playing with linux, I used Midnight Commander to travel around files quickly. I'm now using Windows, and took Far Manager as a replacement to MC. There are some big differences, but my biggest problem right now is that far is useless as is.

Lets say I am in cmd in C:\ , I type far . . (to open both tabs in current folder instead of the far default), then I travel in the first tab to \Program Files\code\etc - now I want to exit far (F10) in this folder. If I F10 it reverts me back to the original folder (C:).

I've looked everywhere but the documentation is lacking.

Comment: I almost never start Far Manager from cmd. I usually start all other programs from FAR. What is the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process (not each console) has its own 'current directory', and processes cannot alter the 'current directory' of any another process – not in Windows and not in Linux.

The MC behavior you've described has to be implemented using other ways than simply exiting:

- Instead of exiting via F10, you tell MC to open a new shell *inside* by pressing Ctrl+O (which only hides MC but doesn't actually return to the parent shell). You can use the same Ctrl+O shortcut in FAR.
- Instead of running MC directly, you run it through a bash alias/function which waits for MC to exit, looks in some agreed-upon location to find the last path MC used, and changes the shell's "current directory" to that path. (This requires cooperation from MC to actually store the path somewhere.) This could be done in Windows Cmd by using a .bat script, but only if FAR has a way of performing actions "before exit".

Comment: You are right about using Ctrl+O, I forgot about that. I just checked on the ubuntu installed on Windows and you're right that mc's default behaviour is to exit in the initial folder, just like far. I'll try the option you said with a batch script. Hopefully it works.

Comment: Batch script is just one ingredient. (It is suitable because Cmd scripts run in-process – more like bash functions than bash scripts.) But it still needs some cooperation from Far Manager.